PrimeNG p-inputMask Removing the Leading '9' from Dial Codes in Custom Phone Number Input Component
I've created my own custom component for a country-flag dropdown and currently I'm facing an issue where if a user selects a country that has a incorrect placeholder like this +_3 ___ ___ ____. This issue is only for dials code with 9s in them.
`
/**
* Handles the event when a country is selected, updating the dial code, mask, and placeholder.
* @param isoCode2 The ISO code of the selected country.
*/
public onCountryChange(isoCode2: string): void {
if (!isoCode2) {
this.resetPhoneNumberField();
return;
}
    const selectedCountry = this.countries.find((country) => country.isoCode2 === isoCode2);
    if (selectedCountry) {
        this.selectedCountry = selectedCountry;
        this.selectedDialCode = selectedCountry.dialCodes[0];

        this.phoneNumberMask = this.getPhoneNumberMask(selectedCountry.isoCode2);
        this.phoneNumberPlaceholder = this.createPlaceholderFromMask(this.phoneNumberMask);

        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(`+${this.selectedDialCode}`);
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.markAsDirty();
        this.phoneNumberChange.emit(`+${this.selectedDialCode}`);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
}

/**
 * Generates the mask pattern for the phone number input based on the selected country.
 * @param isoCode The ISO code of the selected country.
 * @returns The mask pattern for the phone number.
 */
private getPhoneNumberMask(isoCode: string): string {
    try {
        const exampleNumber = this.phoneNumberUtil.getExampleNumberForType(isoCode, PhoneNumberType.MOBILE);
        if (exampleNumber) {
            const formattedExample = this.phoneNumberUtil.format(exampleNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL);
            return this.createMaskFromPhoneNumber(formattedExample);
        }
        return "";
    } catch (error) {
        return "";
    }
}

/**
 * Converts a phone number example into a mask pattern.
 * @param phoneNumber The example phone number.
 * @returns The mask pattern based on the phone number.
 */
private createMaskFromPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: string): string {
    let mask = phoneNumber.replace(/\d/g, "9");
    if (this.selectedDialCode) {
        mask = `+${this.selectedDialCode} ${mask}`;
    }
    return mask;
}

/**
 * Converts a mask pattern into a placeholder for the phone number input.
 * @param mask The mask pattern for the phone number.
 * @returns The placeholder string for the phone number input.
 */
private createPlaceholderFromMask(mask: string): string {
    let placeholder = mask.replace(/9/g, "_");
    if (this.selectedDialCode) {
        const dialCodeLength = this.selectedDialCode.length;
        placeholder = `+${this.selectedDialCode}${placeholder.slice(dialCodeLength + 1)}`;
    }
    return placeholder;
}

/**
 * Handles the phone number input event, updating the formatted phone number and validation status.
 * @param event The input event from the phone number field.
 */
public onPhoneNumberInput(event: any): void {
    const inputElement = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const inputValue = inputElement.value.trim();

    if (this.phoneNumberInputTimer) {
        clearTimeout(this.phoneNumberInputTimer);
    }

    if (!inputValue) {
        this.isPhoneNumberValid = true;
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue("");
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.markAsDirty();
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
        return;
    }

    const dialCode = this.extractDialCode(inputValue);
    const phoneNumberWithoutDialCode = inputValue.replace(dialCode, "");

    this.phoneNumberInputTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        const formattedPhoneNumber = this.formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumberWithoutDialCode, true);
        this.isPhoneNumberValid = this.validatePhoneNumber(formattedPhoneNumber);
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.setValue(formattedPhoneNumber);
        this.form.get(this.controlName)?.markAsDirty();
        this.phoneNumberChange.emit(formattedPhoneNumber);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }, 500);

    const countryCode = this.getCountryCodeFromPhoneNumber(inputValue);
    if (countryCode) {
        const isoCode = this.phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(parseInt(countryCode));
        if (isoCode) {
            this.updateCountrySelectionByIsoCode(isoCode);
        }
    } else {
        this.resetToDefaultCountry();
    }
}

`
I can see the problem is in the method createPlaceHolder where the mask comes in as: "+91 999999 99999" and the regex sets placeholder to "+_1 ______ _____".
I tried doing something like if number starts with +, only do the regex after the first space like this:
`
private createPlaceholderFromMask(mask: string): string {
const firstSpaceIndex = mask.indexOf(' ');
if (firstSpaceIndex !== -1) {
    // Replace digits after the first space with underscores
    const dialCode = mask.substring(0, firstSpaceIndex + 1); // Include the space
    const phoneNumberPart = mask.substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1).replace(/\d/g, "_");
    return dialCode + phoneNumberPart;
} else {
    // If no space is found, fall back to replacing all digits (not typical for valid masks)
    return mask.replace(/\d/g, "_");
}

}
`
But that also didn't work - any help would be appreciated!
